# Possible to use a Parameter to match the XMLNamespace in SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, xml

**XML:**

```
<ZZZ:PRODUCT xmlns:ZZZ="123"><ZZZ:CONTENT>Blank</ZZZ:CONTENT>/ZZZ:PRODUCT>
```

ZZZ will change depending on the entity. How in SQL can i pass the parameter through and only return the ones that match? Below is what i have and want to add the @Entity Parameter into.

**SQL:**

```
@Entity varchar(10)

SELECT * FROM Products

WHERE Products.productDetailXML.exist('//ZZZ:PRODUCT') = 1
```

Comment: What concrete database are you using? They all speak "SQL" as their query language - but things like XML support varies quite a bit from vendor to vendor. So please update your tags with the concrete database you're using - whether that's MySQL, Postgres, Sybase, IBM DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, Interbase - or whatever else it might be you're using!

Comment: SQL Server. It's updated. Thanks

Comment: In XPath you can also select ignoring the namespace like this: `//*[local-name() = "PRODUCT"]`, which you might be able to use if you don't care about the namespace.

Comment: @helderdarocha - Well that's sort of the entire problem. The namespace. Thats the dynamic part that changes "ZZZ". i just need to figure out how to specific if the parameter matches the namespace to only pull those.

Comment: Can't you build that string outside the query and send it as a parameter?

Comment: Does the namespace `123` change or is it just the namespace alias `ZZZ` that is different between XML's?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - namespace 123 will not change. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want here but I am going to provide an answer anyway.

You don't have to take care of the situations where the namespace prefix is different. It is the namespace that matter when you do the query. The query you have does not work because you have not specified what namespace the prefix `ZZZ` belongs to.

This query will give you all rows that are using the namespace `123`.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('123' as ns)
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE Products.productDetailXML.exist('//ns:PRODUCT') = 1
```

It does not matter if the prefix is `ZZZ`

```xml
<ZZZ:PRODUCT xmlns:ZZZ="123">
  <ZZZ:CONTENT>Blank</ZZZ:CONTENT>
</ZZZ:PRODUCT>
```

or something else entirely like `A`.

```xml
<A:PRODUCT xmlns:A="123">
  <A:CONTENT>Blank</A:CONTENT>
</A:PRODUCT>
```

you will still get the rows that uses the namespace `123`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65609/1)

Comment: I believe you are right. i need to move the dynamic parts to 123 instead of ZZZ, as that will not work.